# Android Signed APK showing incomplete

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have signed the application using Eclipse's Export Wizard. When I published this, users started complaining that the application is behaving incorrectly. (Basically, the APK did not have necessary images & audio and hence showing incorrect behaviour).

Some information on Application and Signing which I have tried.

1. I have a lite version and paid version. Both are signed with same keypair. The lite version is working perfectly and full version is giving error.
2. I have tried to export the signed packages again and tried to install directly in device (instead of uploading to market). Same behaviour (i.e Lite apps works correctly and full version not proper)
3. Both Full Version and Lite Version uses shared Library (Code base is identical. Differences as follows.
4. Full Version has 5 times the resources of lite version. The lite version apk is ~2.6MB and full version is ~10.4MB. *In Full Version I have 170 images (mostly png's of 5-10 KB) and ~55mp3 files. In Lite Version I have 45 images and 15 mp3s*
5. Full Version has LVL (License Verification) implemented and Lite Version doesnot. Once LVL is passed, the code simply calls the Library Class
6. If I use Eclipse to build and deploy full version to phone (or emulator), it works correctly. (I guess this build and deploy will use debug key for signing)
7. I have error handling within the code to show code to show a dummypic (a question mark) if resource is missing. All my images are replaced with that question mark. Just to add.. This dummypic is in the Library and all other resources(images) are in Full Version.
8. I have checked the resources by renaming the signed apk file to .zip (thanks to NickT for suggesting this approach). All resource files (audio and images) are present in the zip file.

Any help is appreciated. The application is already in market and hence would like to minimise adverse impact.

**Removed LVL. Still same error**

Tried commenting the LVL code and directly calling the intent. Still same error. 
By commenting the LVL, the code base for Lite and Full Version is identical. Only the resouce count is different. The full version has all the resources of Lite Version + ~5times the resource.

**Update** 
This is how I temporarily fixed it. 
I removed the library project and moved all classes and resources to the Implementation Project (Full Version). Now it is working.

As said, this is a temp fix only. I still need to know how I can fix this with library. Else I will have to create a lot of duplication of code.

Comment: please, show the stacktrace of an error.

Comment: There is no stacktrace for this error. I have error handling within the code to show code to show a dummypic (a question mark) if resource is missing. All my images are replaced with that question mark. Just to add.. This dummypic is in the Library and all other resources(images) are in Full Version.

Comment: If you rename the apk that's actually released to .zip and then look in the res folder when it's unzipped, do you see the resources you expect being present?

Comment: @NickT Checked it. Yes. All resources are in there. PS. Never knew APK is zip file. Thanks for that.

Comment: So it's a runtime error not a build error. I can't suggest why they won't load. Perhaps something to do with storage location (internal memory vs SD card?)

Comment: @NickT Haven't made any preferences in the manifest for internal memory vs SD card. Should I ? This error in behaviour is not appearing when I try to deploy from Eclipse Build and Run (I guess this is signed with debug key)

Comment: @NickT Even if I set a preference for app install location, this will not work for pre 2.2android versions. right! I have the issue in all versions.

Comment: No, I wouldn't say anything about 'use external storage', at least you know now it's all internal. You can make a release apk signed with the release key using Eclipse, although I always use Ant. You just need to do File/ Export Android Application, then point the browse window at your release keystore. You'll have to remove the debug version from the device/emulator first, then use adb on the command line to install the release version.

Comment: @NickT Yes I am doing the same. When I did the File-->Export And.app, it asks me for a keystore. This keystore fole is shared by my lite and free versions. All working fine for Lite Version. Seems like something to do with the resources. Is 10MB a huge value. In Full Version I have 170 images (mostly png's of 5-10 KB) and ~55mp3 files. In Lite Version I have 45 images and 15 mp3s

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so, after all it's quite normal to make a 512MB avd. I think I'd make a copy of the project in Eclipse, then put lots of debug messages (logging or Toasts) round the lines where the resources are loaded in that copied version. I'd also create a brand new avd and try running a release signed version of the copied project on that in order to find out why the resources aren't loading

Answer (score 1):

My bet would be that it has to do with [permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html).
The app that is being installed first, will have read-write permissions to that folder, the other will not.

Try using a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) to make your images accesible for both apps!

Comment: nope. Not correct. Either apps doesnt require any permissions

Comment: Ok, so you're not storing the Library on the SDCard or something... All resources are in the application itself. Still, I wonder what happens if you install the full version first, and after that, try to install the Lite version. Both work fine?

Answer (score 0):

The sign **shouldn't affect** your code. I think the problem must be in the source code of Paid version.

Do you test in emulator? from eclipse? You can test the signed apk in emulator too through "*adb install application-signed.apk*".

Comment: As mentioned in #2, I have tried testing the signed package in actual device using adb install path\apkfile.apk. Installation was smooth. No issues. The app comes with error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall and then re-install app, it happens sometimes, when your phone already has the application and you install it again with different resources and files without uninstalling(but overriding), it gives odd behavior,
try uninstall and then re-install should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think  no two apps of the same package name can co exist in a single device. try installing the apps in two different devices.

Comment: there are no two apps of the same package in the device. when the library project gets added to a project, android removes the references to android package.

Comment: I was thinking the same, if both apps have the same package name it will likely cause issues - if it's even possible to install.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

1) Do you have proguard enabled? If yes, try disabling it and test. If it works, you might need to update your proguard.cfg (probably with some -keep public class)

2) Delete your R.java manually and recompile your full version only!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with Android projects using other `Android Library` projects. It looks like the AAPT (or an eclipse ADT part) sometimes fails when creating the R-file ids (So the resources are present, but the id's are not correct).

What quickly fixed the issue for me: Close the "master" project and reopen it having the `Build Automatically` option set or make a clean&rebuild on this project. The next exported APK shouldn't have the resources-not-found issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you let a debug flag into the Manifest file ?