# My published Android application won't install onto devices from the android market

Tags: android, file, package, google-play

I have compiled my application using nbandroid with netbeans 7.0 on a mac. Then keysigned it with jarsigner and aligned it using zipalign. It uploaded to the market with no issue but it will not install on any device giving the error "invalid package file". I have searched many times, but I have only found solutions on how to fix the problem on the device itself. Does anybody know what might be going on here?

Many Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, will it install directly to your phone, from the original local .apk you had supplied the market?  Eclipse IDE is kind of the standard 'round here...

Comment: Yea I am transferring the project to eclipse now and sadly I don't have an android device to test with the only reason I know it didn't even work was that my friends told me when they tried to download it.

Comment: Have you tried to install the final APK file to the emulator? `adb install /path/to/apk` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My app had a similar problem. See this [Android Signed APK showing incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458490/android-signed-apk-showing-incomplete)

In the end, I created an alternative eclipse project, copied all the files from original project and signed it using the original key. Seems like this is some eclipse-android plugin issue.